# Replace word within url and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to replace word with another word in url and redirect but its not wokring due to query string.

Here is eg. Here is the url and i want to redirect it

https://www.custesitetest.com/test_calculator.php?tf=to&loc=staines
to
https://www.custesitetest.com/autoqoute?tf=to&loc=staines

```
RedirectMatch ^/test_calculator.php/(.*)$ https://www.custesitetest.com/autoquote/$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can use this rule in your root `.htaccess`:***

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/test_calculator.php?$ /autoquote
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this with mod_rewrite,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^test_calculator.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)
RewriteRule ^ autoquote?%1 [R=301,L]
```